# Is there a decentralized way to intercommunicate between two Ethereum networks?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, testnets, rinkeby, kovan

If I have `Contract A` deployed to the **Rinkeby Test Netwok**
If I have `Contract B` deployed to the **Kovan Test Netwok**

Then, can we program the contracts to interact with each other like `Contract A` invoking the `Contract B` methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To communicate between two different networks, you need a bridge of some sorts. The most straightforward bridge is an oracle service which relies data between the chains.

To create a decentralized bridge is very difficult. Basically you need decentralized oracles (something similar to Chainlink) and a decentralized backend system which relies the data. The most difficult part is probably the decentralized backend system, especially if it needs to be trustless.

In short: I don't think it's fully possible, and some compromises need to be made.